# Multiple non-linear regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, regression, non-linear-regression

I am looking for any libraries or method which can help me to find a regression equation. The equation is in this format:

> Y=a1*x^a+a2*y^b+a3*z^c+D
>
> where:
>
> - Y is the dependent variable
> - x, y, z are independent variables
> - D is constant
> - a1, a2, a3 are the coefficients
> - a, b, c are the exponents of the independent variables respectively.

I have values of Y and x, y, z stored in a data frame.

Comment: You have 2 routes: either you transform your original `df`  according to your equation and do `LinearRegression` afterwards; or you do [PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) transformation first. The latter is preferable as it's a commonly accepted way of doing polynomial regression of a specific degree. What is your problem?

Comment: What you're attempting to do is dangerous from practical standpoint, as with polynomial of degree 9 you can draw anything, even an elephant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Random Forest Regressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) implementation from scikit learn. It's quite easy to use, you simply do:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
clf = RandomForestRegressor()

# train the model
clf.fit(df[['x','y','z']], df['Y'])

# predict on test data
predict = clf.predict(test_data[['x','y','z']])
```

Make sure train and test data have same number of independent variables.

For more non-linear regressor, check: [scikit-learn ensemble module](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.ensemble)

Comment: The equation might be non-linear in my case, i.e, some of the independent variables might have exponents in fraction.

Comment: you can look at other methods in the sklearn module, each of them have the same api which follows `fit`,`predict` methods to train and predict the model.

Comment: check the edit please.

Comment: While I usually make use of scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to generate initial parameter estimates followed by passing those estimates to scipy's curve_fit() routine, in this particular case my personal opinion is that the error space is so complex that such an approach would be impractical. @YOLO I agree with your advice and upvoted your answer.